# jquery mobile remove class not working on click event

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a button in jQuery mobile:

```
 <a href="#" data-role="button" id="show_edit" data-theme="d" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-corner-left ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-up-d"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-left"><span class="ui-btn-text">Edit</span></span></a>
```

If I do this in the console, it works (the button colour changes):

```
$('#show_edit').removeClass('ui-btn-up-d').addClass('ui-btn-up-a');
```

However, if I do wrapped in a click handler on my page, the class 'ui-btn-up-d' is not getting removed?

```
$('#show_edit').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-up-d').addClass('ui-btn-up-a'); 
                });
```

Edit: I think the answer below is the right one, however here is another way, which is changing the data-theme too:

```
$('#show_edit').attr('data-theme', 'a').attr('class', 'ui-btn ui-corner-left ui-btn-up-a');
```

Comment: Did you check if the click event was triggered? By outputting in the console for exemple? Because it might be triggered on the span. and also, return false to prevent the default behavior of the link anchor.

Comment: Good idea. I did just check and it's registering the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you aren't binding the event at the right time, or it is targeting the wrong element (such as duplicate id's which is very easy to get unintentionally in jQM)

For example, if your current page had an `id="home"`, you would bind it like this:

```
// every time the id="home" page is initialized, run this handler
$(document).on('pageinit','#home',function(){

    // ensure it targets only elements within this page, however it would
    // be better if you didn't use ID's in jQuery Mobile due to the way it 
    // handles pages.
    $('#show_edit',this).click(function() {
        //$(this).removeClass('ui-btn-up-d').addClass('ui-btn-up-a');
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-btn-up-d ui-btn-up-a');
    });

});
```